# Dynamically create IDs for jQuery Mobile elements, then reference them

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an unknown number of elements in an Array that I need to loop through in order to dynamically create a collapsible-set. I'm wondering if it is possible to dynamically create IDs for the elements in the set each time through the loop, so IDs for the Groups and Items I need to append are unique, then reference the dynamic IDs to .append() items.

Here is the collapsible-set I will append to:

```
$('#dealersContentDiv').append('<div id="colapseDiv" data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true"></div>');
```

Can I dynamically create the ID "group1" in the following line:

```
$('#colapseDiv').append('<div id="group1" data-role="collapsible"></div>');
```

and "item1" in the following line:

```
$('#group1').append('<ul id="item1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
```

Then, if that is possible, how would I reference those IDs to append to them as shown in the following:

```
// how do I reference "group1".append()
$('#group1').append('<ul id="item1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');

// how do I reference "item1".append()
$('#item1').append('<li><a href="' + myData.Dealers[i].URL + '">' + myData.Dealers[i].name + '</a></li>');
```

EDIT: To include an example of the loop to dynamically create the IDs:

```
var groupPrefix = 'group';
var groupId = '';
var itemPrefix = 'item';
var itemId = '';

for (i = 1; i < number_of_items; i++) {

    // dynamically create the groupId
    groupId = groupPrefix + i; // group1, group2, ...

    // use the groupID
    $('#colapseDiv').append('<div id="' + groupId + '" data-role="collapsible"></div>');

    // dynamically create the itemId
    itemId = itemPrefix + i; // item1, item2, ...

    // reference the groupId.append(), use the itemId
    $(groupID).append('<ul id="' + itemId + '" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
}
```

Snippet:

```
$('#dealersContentDiv').append('<div id="colapseDiv" data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true"></div>');

// start loop ...

// the first time through the loop, the dynamically created IDs will be "group1" and "item1"
$('#colapseDiv').append('<div id="group1" data-role="collapsible"></div>');
$('#group1').append('<h2>' + myData.Dealers[i].area + '</h2>');
$('#group1').append('<ul id="item1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
$('#item1').append('<li><a href="' + myData.Dealers[i].URL + '">' + myData.Dealers[i].name + '</a></li>');
$('#item1').append('.... // append mutliple <li>s


// the next time though the loop, "group1" changes to "group2" and "item1" changes to "item2"
$('#colapseDiv').append('<div id="group2" data-role="collapsible"></div>');
$('#group2').append('<h2>' + myData.Dealers[i].area + '</h2>');
$('#group2').append('<ul id="item2" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
$('#item2').append('<li><a href="' + myData.Dealers[i].URL + '">' + myData.Dealers[i].name + '</a></li>');
$('#item2').append('.... // append mutliple <li>s


// now "group3" and "item3" 
$('#colapseDiv').append('<div id="group3" data-role="collapsible"></div>');
$('#group3').append('<h2>' + myData.Dealers[i].area + '</h2>');
$('#group3').append('<ul id="item3" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">');
...


// end loop.

$('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');
$('[data-role=content]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Which version of JQM are you using? You want to bind events to dynamically added elements? In which way are you going to use generated IDs'?

Comment: I'm using jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js. I'm not trying to bind events, I'm trying to dynamically create the IDs then append to the dynamically created names. For example, the first time through the loop, the collapsible element will have an id="group1" (the number will increment and be append to the string "group"). Then, I need to be able to .append() to the "group1" element. Sorry, I know it's confusing, but I can't come up with a better way of explaining it. Hope that helps.

Comment: check this answer, it's similar to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136930/dynamically-adding-collapsible-divs-by-looping-through-array-elements-with-javas/21138251#21138251 if you need explanation/further assistance, feel free.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that code isn't assigning an ID to the element: <div data-role='collapsible'>. What I am trying to do is change that code to: <div data-role='collapsible' id='group1'>, where 'group1' is dynamically created. (The next time through the loop, the id will be 'group2'.) Then, I need to append an element to the 'group1' div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building all the collapsible divs in one loop and the items for each collapsible in and inner loop, you don't really need to assign IDs. Just use jquery variables for the items you create and append to them.

> See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8z5Rz/)**

When I create the DOM elements, I assign them to jQuery variables (collSetDiv, divCol, ul, li, etc.). Then after all loops are completed, the whole collapsible set is appended to the existing parent div in the page.

```
var groupPrefix = 'group';
var groupId = '';
var itemPrefix = 'item';
var itemId = '';

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function(){

    var colSetDIV = $('<div id="colapseDiv" data-role="collapsible-set" data-mini="true"></div>');

    for (var i=0; i < 3; i++){
        groupId = groupPrefix + i; 
        var divCol = $('<div id="' + groupId + '" data-role="collapsible" ></div>');
        divCol.append('<h2>Dealer' + i + '</h2>');
        var ul = $('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>');

        for (var j=0; j < 4; j++){
            var li = $('<li><a href="#">Dealer' + i + ' Name' + j + '</a></li>');
            ul.append(li);
        }
        divCol.append(ul);
        colSetDIV.append(divCol);
    }

    $('#dealersContentDiv').append(colSetDIV);
    colSetDIV.collapsibleset().trigger("create");
});
```

Comment: This is perfect; thanks. I didn't realize I didn't need the IDs.